# Xcode is detaching from runing process when clicking "Stop Build"

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, xcode12

Since I upgraded to XCode 12, the following situation keeps happening:

When I click "Stop" on a running debug build, the build is being slowly stopped (takes 3-5 seconds), then after it has completed,  my app is still running, but detached from XCode.

A workaround that I've found is to add a breakpoint anywhere in the code, then after it's reached, the process seems to attach normally on each subsequent build until I quit XCode. But this is time consuming and does not always work.

I do get this output message:

> Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has exited unexpectedly.
> Please file a bug if you have reproducible steps.

I am running: XCode 12, Catalina, macOS Swift project.

Any ideas? Is there a new setting in XCode that I missed?

Comment: Try deleting your Xcode derived data

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried, it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @ErikAigner nope.